# putting an underscore in its place

Tags: jquery

how do I take the string using jQuery

```
Standard Class
```

and turn it into this

```
Standard_Class
```

if this is the id

```
$('#some_id').text;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do everything needs to be done with jQuery? How about a regex:

```
var result = 'Standard Class'.replace(/\s/g, '_');
```

and to modify the text into an existing element jQuery could be useful:

```
$('#some_id').text($('#some_id').text().replace(/\s/g, '_'));
```

Comment: Don't mess with their religion, or John will come after you.

Comment: This reminds me of a [picture](http://img180.imageshack.us/img180/3305/addanumbertoanothernumb.png) :-)